# When does PendingIntent start the activity

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

When does a `PendingIntent` tied to a notification manager start its activity? 
Does it start when the user taps on the notification or when the the notification manager creates the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user taps on the notification.